# Custom field type rendering in XSLT

Tags: custom-field-types, xslt, caml-renderpattern

How can I render a custom field type with XSLT.
I want to render in the same manner like I do with this CAML

```
<RenderPattern Name="DisplayPattern">
    <Switch>
    <Expr>
        <Column/>
    </Expr>
    <Case Value="" />
    <Default>
        <Column SubColumnNumber="0" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
        <HTML><![CDATA[, nr.&nbsp;]]></HTML>
        <Column SubColumnNumber="1" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
        <HTML><![CDATA[<br/>Bloc&nbsp;]]></HTML>
        <Column SubColumnNumber="2" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
        <HTML><![CDATA[,&nbsp;Etaj&nbsp;]]></HTML>
        <Column SubColumnNumber="3" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
        <HTML><![CDATA[,&nbsp;Sc.&nbsp;]]></HTML>
        <Column SubColumnNumber="4" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
        <HTML><![CDATA[,&nbsp;Ap.&nbsp;]]></HTML>
        <Column SubColumnNumber="5" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
        <HTML><![CDATA[<br/>]]></HTML>
        <Column SubColumnNumber="6" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
        <HTML><![CDATA[,&nbsp;Jud/Sec&nbsp;]]></HTML>
        <Column SubColumnNumber="7" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
        <HTML><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></HTML>
        <Column SubColumnNumber="8" HTMLEncode="TRUE"/>
    </Default>
  </Switch>
</RenderPattern>
```

I've tried with an XSL file like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" 
            version="1.0"
            exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" 
            xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
            xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" 
            xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
            xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" 
            xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" ddwrt:oob="true">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@FieldType='AdresaField']" mode="Note_body">
<xsl:param name="thisNode" select="." />
<xsl:variable name="curElement" select="current()" />
<xsl:variable name="fldVal">
  <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@*[name()=$curElement/@Name]"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($fldVal, 1, 3)"/> - Just to show it's working. Here I don't know how to do
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the following link useful for you? http://www.intheknow.it/customxsltfieldrendering.ashx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is the link which I read before posting here.

Comment: The main reason for this is because pages will disappear, as this one has. SO the answer is now gone.